# Ionic header doesn't refresh in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i have a view in templates as

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive" title="Home"></ion-header-bar>
<ion-view view-title="Home">


<ion-content class="grey-bg">
<div class="list card">
<a ng-click="click();"> <div class="" > <i class="ion-ios-camera cicon"></i>        </div></a>
    ....</ion-content></ion-view>
```

and inside the controller i have a function

```
     $scope.click = function(){
     $state.go('app.click',{},{reload:true});}
```

the page navigate properly but the trouble is that when i test it in my browser the contents in the header disappear when i try the back button and it reappears when i refresh that page. Can anyone point out what i am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It disappears because you have reloaded the page. Is there any reason for using `reload: true`? Maybe you might wanna reload just that state with `reload: app.click`

Comment: thanks for the reply...but i am not facing the issue when i navigate to the click page rather the problem starts when i return back to home page from the click page. u got any idea on that one...????

Comment: also the issue is not only affecting my side nav but also hides my back button and my app closes on pressing the device's back button.

Comment: Yeah, for same reasons as I mentioned in earlier comment. Using `reload :true` reloads the application to that state. Means this new view becomes the back view for the previous view. Get rid of the reload option if you don't have a genuine need for it

Comment: i tried it but the problem still persists.I have tried other option that i read online like  adding "enable-menu-with-back-views="true" to my view and "$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event, viewData) {
  viewData.enableBack = true;
 });" in my controller.

Comment: Can you share a plunkr?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137122/discussion-between-vin-and-ladmerc).